# Redirect after submitting multiple forms

Tags: javascript, jquery

There is a submit button that [serializes](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/) some forms and submits them correspondingly to different handlers on the server. When the data have been sent, I would like to redirect to another page where the user can see an overview of the results. How can I do it so? Redirecting right away does not work since the page does not have enough time to submit the data (or it looks so).

The following fails:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#submit_all_button').submit(function(){
        var querystring = $('#q1').serialize();

        $.get('/change_q1', querystring);

        var querystring = $('#q2').serialize();
        $.get('/change_q2', querystring);

        var querystring = $('#q3').serialize();
        $.get('/change_q3', querystring);

        window.location.href = "/main";
        return false;
    });
});
```

The same problem arises when the submit action is to redirect to `/main` page.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `success function` of [jQuery get()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/) and keep track whether all your updates are send. So the last success function call finally redirects your page.

Answer (score 0):

I have an other answer in PHP which is interesting: run it as a background job (Other answer is the best way to go but if, for some reason, you can't use it):

```
set_time_limit(900);
ignore_user_abort(true);
header("Connection: close");
header("Content-Length: " . mb_strlen('ok'));
echo 'ok';
flush();
// Your code follows here
```

Maybe you can use this logic in your server-side language.